# Does TexShop have "realtime" pdf previewing?

Tags: texshop

Is TexShop supposed to have "realtime" pdf previewing? I can press typeset to get a pdf preview but any further edits do not show up. Is there a way to make it happen (I think oveleaf has this feature). Or are there any other latex editors that have this feature? Also random question, but why does the pdf preview in TexShop have a grey background instead of a white one?

Comment: TeXShop uses a separate TeX Distrubution, e.g., TeX Live installed by MacTeX, to do the type setting so you need to typeset manually and the preview will update. There used to be some macros that set up a daemon to continually update but I don't know if they still work. And latexmk can be set up to do that but that’s a separate procedure.